# CentOS 8 does not resolve DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, ip

Here is the very strange issue with freshly installed CentOS 8.0
I configured static IP with nmcli which essentially using NetworkManager. So turning it of is not an option as I want to follow RedHat's standard way of managing the system.

Here is some info:

```
#ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Contents of 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp14s0

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp14s0
UUID=d64e6ca1-c30d-41ea-a4bb-49445d89aac4
DEVICE=enp14s0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=18.25.16.249
GATEWAY=18.1.0.1
PREFIX=19
DNS1=18.0.70.160
DNS2=18.0.72.3
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 18.0.70.160
nameserver 18.0.72.3
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp14s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:fd:a1:c6:d6:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 18.25.16.249/19 brd 18.25.31.255 scope global noprefixroute enp14s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9864:a2af:89e8:e78d/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:fd:a1:c6:d6:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

pinging any IP directly work just fine
ping 172.217.7.14

```
PING 172.217.7.14 (172.217.7.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.7.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=6.30 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.7.14: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=6.30 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.7.14: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=6.30 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.7.14: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=5.82 ms
```

I have rebooted and stopped NetworkManger no dice here. DHCP works but I need a static IP. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you ping your nameservers? Try using `dig` or `nslookup` to see if DNS is resolving.

Comment: To expand on Bert's comment, try two tests: `dig google.com @18.0.70.160` and `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`. From outside MIT's network (where you appear to be located) they give different results, but that may simply be due to filtering to avoid [a DNS amplification attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Amplification). It changes the correct answer if you get an answer from the w20ns.mit.edu vs. getting the same behavior as those of us out here on the wider Internet.

Comment: What is inside `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?